# Write delta file to S3 (MinIO) - PySpark 2.4.3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, minio, delta-lake

I am currently trying to write a `delta-lake` `parquet` file to S3, which I replace with a MinIO locally.

I can perfectly fine read/write standard `parquet` files to `S3`.

However, when I use the [delta lake example](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html)

Configure [delta to s3](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#configuration-for-s3)

It seems I can't write `delta_log/` to my `MinIO`.

So I tried to set: `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl` and `fs.s3a.impl`.

I am using `pyspark[sql]==2.4.3` which I use in my current `venv`.

`src/.env`:

```sh
# pyspark packages
DELTA = io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.3.0
HADOOP_COMMON = org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3
HADOOP_AWS = org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = ${HADOOP_AWS},${HADOOP_COMMON},${DELTA}
```

`src/spark_session.py`:

```py
# configure s3 connection for read/write operation (native spark)
hadoop_conf = sc.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", self.aws_endpoint_url)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", self.aws_access_key_id)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", self.aws_secret_access_key)
# hadoop_conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")  #  when using hadoop 2.8.5
# hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")  #  alternative to above hadoop 2.8.5
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
hadoop_conf.set("spark.history.fs.logDirectory", 's3a://spark-logs-test/')
```

`src/apps/raw_to_parquet.py`

```py
# Trying to write pyspark dataframe to MinIO (S3)

raw_df.coalesce(1).write.format("delta").save(s3_url)
```

---

`bash`:

```sh
# RUN CODE
spark-submit --packages $(PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS) src/run_onlineretailer.py
```

Error with `hadoop-common: 2.7.3`, `hadoop-aws: 2.7.3`: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<init>(java.net.URI, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)`

So with this error I then updated to `hadoop-common: 2.8.5`, `hadoop-aws: 2.8.5`, to fix the `NoSuchMethodException`. Because `delta` needs: `S3AFileSystem`

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`

So to me it seems that the `parquet` file can be written without a problem, however, delta creates these `delta_log` folder which cannot be recognised (I think?).

Current [source code](https://github.com/Thelin90/berserkr/pull/4).

Read several different similar questions but nobody seem to have been trying with `delta lake` files.

**UPDATE**

It currently work with these settings:

```sh
#pyspark packages
DELTA_LOGSTORE = spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore
DELTA = io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.3.0
HADOOP_COMMON = org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.7
HADOOP_AWS = org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.7
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = ${HADOOP_AWS},${HADOOP_COMMON},${DELTA}
PYSPARK_CONF_ARGS = ${DELTA_LOGSTORE}
```

```py
# configure s3 connection for read/write operation (native spark)
hadoop_conf = sc.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", self.aws_endpoint_url)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", self.aws_access_key_id)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", self.aws_secret_access_key)
```

```sh
spark-submit --packages $(PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS) --conf $(PYSPARK_CONF_ARGS) src/run_onlineretailer.py
```

The weird thing is that it will only work like this.

If I try to set it with `sc.conf` or `hadoop_conf` it does not work, see uncommented code:

```py
def spark_init(self) -> SparkSession:

    sc: SparkSession = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(self.app_name) \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", self.warehouse_location) \
        .getOrCreate()

    # set log level
    sc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    # Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
    sc.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

    # sc.conf.set("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore") # does not work

    # configure s3 connection for read/write operation (native spark)
    hadoop_conf = sc.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", self.aws_endpoint_url)
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", self.aws_access_key_id)
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", self.aws_secret_access_key)
    #hadoop_conf.set("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore") # does not work

    return sc
```

If somebody can explain this, it would be great. Is it because `.getOrCreate()`? Seems impossible to set the `conf` without this call? Except in the command line when running application.

Comment: Can you try with a Spark package with Hadoop included?
Also you need to put all conf calls, especially logStore, before SparkSession creation. See https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html

Answer (score -1):

you are mixing hadoop-* jars; just like the spark ones, they only work if they are all from the same release

Comment: Okay but I don't see how I am mixing them? Because I use the same version for both? Is it because when I import `pyspark` it has its own version of `hadoop` and when I give it `packages` it is not for the same?

Because it works now if I give it as a `conf` parameter, and I set the `fs.*` endpoints with the `sc.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()`.

Comment: It would be quite helpful to point out where the mixed version is happening.

Comment: ..I don't know where the mixed version is happening. I do recognise inconsistent JAR versions. This is a deployment/configuration problem and so, sadly, whoever sees the problem gets to fix. Me: I'd run storediag or some other way to locate the JARs hosting the conflicting classes https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore